# Flex Slider Not working properly Last Slide

Tags: javascript

**I'm new to JS and This kind of slider**
I've an issue related to style in Flex Slider(thumbnail-slider) . In the last slide of the image It generates extra space and the image goes on the left of the screen thats why the last slide not showing properly..

Here is Code of script:-

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#flex_carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    itemWidth: 380,
    itemMargin: 5,
    maxItems: 3,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    pauseOnAction: false, 
    asNavFor: '#flex_main_slider'
  });

  $('#flex_main_slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,

    animationSpeed:1000,
    slideshowSpeed:2000,
    sync: "#flex_carousel",
    start: function(slider){
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

and this the code on page to show the slider..

```
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="images/frex1.jpg" />
                <div class="flex-thumbnal-area">
                <span>Producing<h4>Quality</h4></span>
                <input type="submit" name="button" class="flex-btn" value="Explore More" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="images/frex2.jpg" />
                <div class="flex-thumbnal-area">
                <span>Producing<h4>Quality</h4></span>
                <input type="submit" name="button" class="flex-btn" value="Explore More" />
                </div>
            </li>
```

Help Me Out...
ASAP
Thank's In Advance..

Answer (score -1):

you are missing a few things here:

- calling `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready`
- calling flexslider twice with incorrect selectors

in markup which are necessary for this slider plugin to work. Also, you are calling flexslider function twice and with incorrect selectors. Please see working [sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYYZy/6/).